# How to keep a running total in assembly code? ARM cortex M3 (Keil software)

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

Total beginner here. I'm trying to keep a running total of R5 but it keeps resetting back to the original value I had it set to. R3 is keeping up but R5 won't

This is the part of the problem I am working on.

[Summation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJzNq.png)

```
lessThan
    CMP R3, R4
    ADD R5, R3, R3
    RSB R5, R5, #60
    ADDLE R3, R3, #1
    ADD R5, R5, #6
    ADD R5, R5, R4
    BLE lessThan
```

I am ending up with my R5 being (in decimal) 48 when it's actually supposed to be 780.

Comment: what is the initial value of r3 and r4?

Comment: Single-step your code with a debugger and see which instruction changes `r5` in a way you don't expect.

Answer (score 0):

`ADD R5, R3, R3` sets `r5 = r3*2`, throwing away the old value of R5 inside every loop iteration.

Did you mean `add r5, r5, r3` to do `r5 += r3`?  Or did you need a scratch register?

IDK what you want your code to do, or why, but the my first paragraph is the answer to why `R5` isn't accumulating a separate total.